# Remove source to source drag and drop in fieldchoose.js

Tags: javascript

I have to create drag and drop feature to move item from one area to another. For this purpose, I am using `fieldchooser.js`. It helps me to drag and drop from source to source, source to destination, destination to source and destination to destination. But I want to remove drag and drop from source to source. How is it possible in `fieldchooser.js`?

Answer (score 0):

I've an idea to solve your problem. There is not way to avoid the drag&drop in the same columns, but I thought that one way to avoid this behaviour is to disable the items on mousedown and reactivate them on mouseup.
The idea, in a nutshell, is to set as blocked all the items that you don't want move in the same list ( here there is the jquery doc about [this](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items) ) and reset all the things when it's moved in the other list, with a mouseup.
 Here there is a javascript that I used to test this solution.

```
$( "#sourceFields div" ).mousedown(function(){  
     $(this).siblings().addClass("ui-state-disabled");
     $( "#sourceFields" ).sortable({
      items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"
        });
    });
$( "#sourceFields div" ).mouseup(function(){  
     $(this).siblings().removeClass("ui-state-disabled");
     $( "#sourceFields" ).sortable({
      items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"
    });
});
```

you need, anyway, manage some side effects on this solution. This script is not complete to resolve all the behaviours, but maybe is a little step for a solution.

I hope can be useful.

Comment: Thanks Giuseppe for your answer. It disabled all items in source list and then I can't move item even to destination list. But it should be movable from source to destination.

Comment: Hi Vipin, I've developed an example that you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/cus041kL/1/ there are two side effect in my case, the first one is that when you move from dest to source, the item is moved in the last position. the second is that you have to give focus on the sourcelist to reactive the items. Sorry :)

Comment: And move item from source to destination work sometime and sometime it doesn't work. But thanks some work around for me.:)